# Type Inference with Reflection and DataKinds

Tags: haskell, reflection, type-inference, data-kinds

I'm having problems getting GHC to infer a type in a place where it should be obvious. Below is a complete snippet demonstrating the problem.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, KindSignatures, TypeOperators, GADTs #-}

import Data.Reflection
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Tagged

-- heterogeneous list, wrapping kind [*] as *
data HList :: [*] -> * where
              HNil :: HList '[]
              HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)

main = test2

test1 = do
    let x = HCons 3 HNil :: HList '[Int]
        c = case x of (HCons w HNil) -> w
    print c

test2 = reify True (\(_::Proxy a) -> do

    let x = HCons (Tagged 3) HNil :: HList '[Tagged a Int]
        c = case x of (HCons w HNil) -> w
    print $ untag (c :: Tagged a Int))
```

In `test1`, I can print `c` without giving `c` and explicit type, just as I expect. The type of `c` is inferred by the explicit signature on `x`: namely, the first element in the `HList` has type `Int`.

In `test2`, however, the explicit signature on `c` is required. If I simply `print $ untag c` in `test2`, I get

```
Test.hs:22:32:
    Couldn't match type `s0' with `s'
      `s0' is untouchable
           inside the constraints (as ~ '[] *)
           bound at a pattern with constructor
                      HNil :: HList ('[] *),
                    in a case alternative
      `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context:
            Reifies * s Bool => Proxy * s -> IO ()
          at Test.hs:19:9
    Expected type: Tagged * s0 Int
      Actual type: a
    In the pattern: HNil
    In the pattern: HCons w HNil
    In a case alternative: (HCons w HNil) -> w
```

Why can GHC not infer the type of `c` from the explicit type given to `x` as in `test1`?

Comment: for what it's worth, the older-style `data HCons a b = HCons a b` `data HNil = HNil` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I've found these errors to be related to let-bindings... though I don't know the precise cause or if it's actually bug in GHC. The workaround is to use a case statement instead: https://gist.github.com/NathanHowell/39748c25999548fe56ac

Comment: @NathanHowell: Interesting, and very annoying.

Comment: @Eric: I agree. I understand why this happens with GADTs or ExistentialQuantification when they're introducing new type variables into scope... this doesn't though and seems like it should work. Hopefully someone chimes in.

Comment: @NathanHowell: This post isn't attracting much attention it seems. If you write your comment up and include the code in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found these errors to be related to let-bindings... though I don't know the precise cause or if it's actually bug in GHC. The workaround is to use a case statement instead:

```
test4 = reify True $ \ (_::Proxy a) -> do
  let x = HCons (Tagged 4) HNil :: HList '[Tagged a Int]
      c = case x of (HCons w HNil) -> w
  print $ untag (c :: Tagged a Int)

test5 = reify True $ \ (_::Proxy a) -> do
  case HCons (Tagged 5) HNil :: HList '[Tagged a Int] of
    HCons w HNil -> print $ untag w
```